# Store data in redux individually from a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using `redux` to store some `datas` into the state and I'm facing a problem.

The `API` I'm calling is returning a collection of datas. By putting it into the store I got something like that:

```
Datas[0]: [{
  name: foo,
  desc: bar
 },
 {
  name: foo,
  desc: bar
 },
]
```

If I do a second call, I'll still get another collection and it will look like that in the store :

```
Datas[0]: [{
  name: foo,
  desc: bar
 },
 {
  name: foo,
  desc: bar
 },
],
Datas[1]: [{
  name: foo,
  desc: baz
 },
 {
  name: foo,
  desc: baz
 },
]
```

[actual model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WptqE.png)

I want to have a library of data. So is it possible to put each data (object) into a new array for each call ? In that case I'd be able to map all the data easily.

Here is my saga : https://gist.github.com/blaadje/07479d44e8537076406368a3a50b49f8
reducer: https://gist.github.com/blaadje/0e0a07da9723bb1315e518dede87e2f7

I was thinking about calling the `API_FETCH_SUCCESS` multiple times by mapping each item of the collection but it would be hell.

If u guys have any idea or if its possible or not

Comment: so you want to save an array of arrays in store? like this `[ [{name: foo},{desc: baz}], [{name: foo},{desc: baz}] ]` ?

Comment: Something like this:
```Datas[0]: [{
  name: foo,
  desc: bar
 }
],
Datas[1]: [
  name: foo,
  desc: baz
 }
],
Datas[2]: [
  name: foo,
  desc: baz
 }
]
```

Comment: Since every collection is an array of object like `[{name: 'foo', desc: 'bar'},{ name: 'foo', desc: 'bar'}]` and initially your state is an empty array so you can do this: `let newState = state.concat([{name: 'foo', desc: 'bar'},{ name: 'foo', desc: 'bar'}].map(item => [item]));` ***newState*** will contain a new array in your desired format.

Comment: so let say collection is an array fetched from api `collection.map(item => [item]);` will return an array of arrays. you just need to contact this array with your existing sate which in fact is an array.